# Can I query if a subscriber has any scheduled emails in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

I am aware that we can look at the `_Sent` [data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) to see what emails have been sent to Subscribers in past context.

What I would like to know if there is a way we can query if there are any scheduled sends for a particular person?

I know the `_Job` view you can see what emails are scheduled to be sent out, however this is only an overview of the job and from what I can see it doesn't contain information about what Subscribers are in the job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u tried joining job to subscribers Data view?

Comment: Joining to what is the question

Comment: If memory serves me right, you can’t access subscribers directly from job. Join with sent on jobid and join that with subscribers on subscriberid

Comment: But joint with Sent will still only show records that have been sent already, not scheduled right?

Answer (score 0):

You can query like below

```
Select S.SubscriberId, J.SchedTime 
from _Sent S
inner join _Job J
on J.JobID = S.JobID
where S.SubscriberID = 'Input the SubscriberID in question'
```

The above will give you if a subscriberId is part of the scheduled send.